# Can the [miniatures] and [model-making] tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have a [model-building](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/model-building) and [miniatures](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/miniatures) tag.
The former is used for 5 questions, the latter for 15.

I am not entirely sure about the nuances in the use of either word, as English is not my first language, but I guess there is a considerable overlap.
I imagine miniatures fall under model-building, but that model-building is not necessarily about miniatures. Is that a correct assumption?

We can leave both tags 'as-are', or set one as a synonym for the other.

**What are your thoughts on this?**

Answer (score 3):

Draft of suggested changes to the tag text.

[model-building](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/model-building)

Excerpt:

> Model building is the process of creating a physical representation of an object or idea.  Use this tag for questions about model building as a craft, or any aspect of the process, preferably in combination with the tag for the specific procedure your question is about. For questions about miniatures, use the [miniatures] tag instead.

Tag text (no changes to links portion):

> Model building is the process of creating a physical representation of an object or idea.  It is used for such purposes as illustrating a concept or intended appearance, prototyping an idea, or replicating an object, at least in appearance, at the same or a different scale.
>
> Model building can entail a range of crafts, from scale models (of trains, planes, cars, etc.), scenery for board games, model figures or miniatures, to architectural models and matchstick models.  It can involve creating a replica from scratch, using materials and components similar to the actual item, assembling a kit of prepared components that yield a result similar in appearance to the actual item, or using completely different kinds of materials with a completely different form of construction to yield a result resembling the appearance of the actual item.

[miniatures](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/miniatures)

Excerpt only (no changes to links portion):

> Questions related to making, painting, basing, or repairing small scale models and miniatures. Use for questions in which the miniature size differentiates unique requirements, preferably in combination with the tag for the specific procedure your question is about.

Comment: I agree that both tags are **not** synonymous. This proposal makes the difference clearer (if users actually read the tag descriptions), but it's also consistent with the common uses of the words "miniature" and "model".

Comment: OK. I went ahead and incorporated the changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right that model building is not necessarily miniatures.  I think the term can even be applied to what's essentially prototyping, or making full-sized props.

In relation to miniature scale, it's also possible that some people make an additional distinction that "miniatures" refer to individual objects, where "modeling" could potentially refer to collections of objects (a model cityscape could contain miniatures of buildings, cars, people, trees, etc.).

My inclination would be to leave both tags as they are.

Comment: I agree, but looking at the description of both tags there is a lot more overlap. Can we create more distinctive descriptions of both tags? On what type of question (maybe based on their respective lists) would you prefer one over another?

Comment: @Joachim, I looked at the lists of tagged questions and did a little cleanup. First impression of the tag descriptions is they seem basically OK. The overlap is that miniatures are a subset of modeling. Maybe we can improve the tag descriptions, but their usage on currently tagged questions seems appropriate. Let me think about the tag text, and maybe some wording about usage.